# How not to make switch statement updated when I return to the menu C++

Tags: c++

After I input numbers, when I return to menu and calculate the sum it outputs correct. But when I return again and enter case 2 again the output doubles its value.

Example: I input 1,2,3,4,5 cin>>return //return to menu //choose 2.Sum //the sum is 15//return to menu again choose 2//the sum now is 4 //also doubles the average.

I'm not finished yet on other parts because my professor wants us to use functions. How can I fix this not to double the value when return? And another thing, my professor wants to display error message when I choose case2-case5 without choosing case 1 first for inputting numbers.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int list(int *listinput);
int printSum(int array[],int a);
int printAverage(int array[],int inputSize);
int ave, sum = 0;

main(){
   int input,menu,low,high;
   int sum1;
   char r;
   int array[100];

   cout << "Enter how many nos to be input: " << endl;
   cin >> input;

   do {

   cout << "\nMENU" << endl;
   cout << "1.Input a list" << endl;
   cout << "2.Sum" << endl;
   cout << "3.Average" << endl;
   cout << "4.Lowest Number" << endl;
   cout<<"5.Highest Number"<<endl;
   cout<<"6.Exit"<<endl;
   cout<<"Select from the menu:";
   cin>>menu;
   switch(menu){
                     case 1:

                          cout<<"\nEnter "<<input<<" nos: ";
                          for(int i=0;i<input;i++){
                           list(&array[i]);
                            }
                          cout<<" The inputted nos: ";
                          for(int i=0;i<input;i++){
                                  cout<<" "<<array[i];
                                  }
                          cout<<"\nEnter r/R to return to the menu";
                          cin>>r;
                          system("cls");
                            break;
                     case 2:

                          cout<<"The Sum is: "<<printSum(array,input);

                          cout<<"\nEnter r/R to return to the menu";
                          cin>>r;
                          system("cls");
                                  break;
                     case 3:

                          cout<<"Average is: "<<printAverage(array,input);
                          cout<<"\nEnter r/R to return to the menu";
                          cin>>r;
                          system("cls");
                          break;
                     case 4:

                           low=array[0];
                           for(int i=0;i<input;i++){
                           if(low>array[i])
                           low=array[i];
                           }
                           cout<<"Lowest Number is: "<<low;
                           cout<<"\nEnter r/R to return to the menu";
                           cin>>r;
                           system("cls");
                           break;
                     case 5:
                          high=array[0];

                          for(int i=0;i<input;i++){

                           if(high<array[i])
                           high=array[i];

                           }
                           cout<<"Highest Number is: "<<high;
                           cout<<"\nEnter r/R to return to the menu";
                           cin>>r;
                           system("cls");
                           break;
                           case 6:

                                break;


                          default:
                                  cout<<"Invalid input";
                     }}
                     while(r=='r'||r=='R');
   getch();
   }
  int list(int *listinput){
  cin>> *listinput;}

  int printSum( int array[],int a )
 {
 for (int i = 0; i <a; i++)
 {

    sum += array[i];
 }

return sum;
}

int printAverage( int array[],int inputSize )
{
     for (int i = 0; i <inputSize; i++)
     {
         sum += array[i];
         ave=sum/inputSize;
     }

     return ave;
 }
```

Comment: This code is not very well formatted or indented, which makes it hard to read.

Comment: I think the code was a breeze compared to the "question".

Comment: I began to fix the code, but it is a nightmare to fix all. I am proposing to close this question now...

Answer (score 3):

Your basic problem is that the variable sum is global - this means that after you call the function printsum its value is retained.

You should declare sum inside the printsum function; then it would be a local variable. This means you get a 'new' one each time. In general it is always better to use local variables if you can; global variables are almost always bad style or outright wrong.